# GraphQL nested query returns null

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am trying to use a GraphQL nested query (I am 80% sure this is a nested query?) to get information on the listing and the chef (author) of the listing. I can get the listing info just fine, but I am unable to get the chef info.

I was under the impression that the default resolver (user) would fire when `getListing(args)` returned without a valid `User` object for the chef. But the default resolver does not appear to be firing.

How do I properly get the nested information?

For example, my query is:

```
query getListing($listingID: String!) {
  getListing(listingID: $listingID) {
    name
    chef {
      firstName
    }
  }
}
```

The query returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getListing": {
      "name": "Test",
      "chef": {
        "firstName": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The function `getListing(args)` queries the DB and returns:

```
{
  name: 'Test',
  chef: 'testUsername',
  listingID: 'testListingID'
}
```

My Schema is:

```
type Listing {
  uuid: String!
  name: String!
  chef: User!
}

type User {
  username: String
  firstName: String
}

type Query {
  getUser(jwt: String!): User
  getListing(listingID: String): Listing
}
```

And my resolvers are:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getListing: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      console.log('GET_LISTING');
      return getListing(args);
    },
    getUser: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      console.log('GET_USER');
      return getUser(args);
    },
  },

  User: async (parent, args) => {
    console.log('USER RESOLVER');
    return getUser(args);
  },
};
```

**Other Info:**
I am using Apollo Server running on AWS Lambda integrating with DynamoDB on the backend.

Comment: Resolvers exist only at the field level. You can't resolve a type (i.e. `User`). You can only resolve a field that has that type.

Comment: @DanielRearden I thought that, but when I put in a resolver for `chef` (similar to the `User` resolver) GraphQL didnt like that at all. How would you properly resolve the chef field? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvers exist only at the field level. You can't resolve a type (i.e. User). You can only resolve a field that has that type (i.e. `chef`).

```
const resolvers = {
  // ...
  Listing: {
    chef: (parent, args) => {
      return getUser()
    }, 
  },
}
```

It's unclear what sort of parameters `getUser` accepts, so you'll need to modify the above example accordingly. You won't use `args` unless you actually specify arguments for the field being resolved in your schema. It looks like the returning listing has a `chef` property that's the name of the user, so you can access that value with `parent.chef`.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! That is the weirdest way of doing it, yet it makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much for sticking with me! I know it takes a lot to explain concepts that seem trivial, yet it really means a lot to me to finally understand. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue - but 'getUser' seems to be limited in that 'chef' cannot be made 'async chef', which would seem to make sense to me when getting data from a database. In this case, 'chef' is just a JSON object that contains a reference to the user object. Or maybe there is some other subtlety that I'm missing here. This also implies that in an array, getUser is called every time.